# In how many ways can 4 balls be distributed in 3 distinct boxes when each box may have any number of balls. Also, 2 balls are identical

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know how to do it for $n$ identical ones being distributed in $k$ distinguishable boxes as $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{n!(k-1)!}$
and for $n$ distinguishable ones being distributed among $k$ boxes as 
$k^n$,
but for this case I am confused.
I guess the answer should be $\frac{3^2 (2+3-1)!}{2!(3-1)!}$ which comes out to be $\frac{9\times4!}{2!2!}=54$.

Comment: Start by putting the two identical balls into the boxes. That is 6 possibilities. For each of these, the other two balls can each be placed in 3 ways. So a total of $3\times3\times6=54$

Comment: Could you explain why that's $6$? For the first ball you have $3$ options. And for the second one you have $3$ options. shouldnt it be $9$?

Comment: so what i thought of is correct ?

Comment: @OriaGruber There are the following combinations (number of identical balls in each box): $$(2,0,0);(0,2,0);(0,0,2);(1,1,0);(0,1,1);(1,0,1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with 1 ball, one of the two identical ones. It can be distributed into 3 distinct boxes in 3 ways, obviously.

Now take the other identical ball.  You can also distribute this one into the 3 distinct boxes in 3 ways. Because the two balls are **identical**, we note that there are only **six** possible arrangements. If they weren't identical, there would be nine, by the multiplication rule. But they're identical, so the possible box arrangements are: $\{[2,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,2],[1,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]\}$. Okay. Now we have six ways to arrange the two balls into the boxes.

Now we take the **distinct ball**. There are, again, three ways to arrange this one into the boxes. By the multiplication rule, we now have $3 \cdot 6 = 18$ ways to arrange the three balls into the boxes.

We have two distinct balls, so we repeat the last step again, for $3 \cdot 18 = 54$ total ways to arrange these four balls.